# SOAPpy - reserved word in named parameter list

Tags: python, soap, soappy, reserved-words

I'm using SOAPpy to access a SOAP Webservice. This call to the function findPathwaysByText works just fine:

```
server.findPathwaysByText (query= 'WP619', species = 'Mus musculus')
```

However, this call to the function login does not:

```
server.login (user='amarillion', pass='*****')
```

Because pass is a reserved word, python won't run this. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
d = {'user':'amarillion', 'pass':'*****' }
server.login(**d)
```

This passes in the given dictionary as though they were keyword arguments (the **)

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
server.login(user='amarillion', **{'pass': '*****'})
```

The double-asterix syntax here applies keyword arguments.  Here's a simple example that shows what's happening:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

kwargs = {"a": 5, "b": 6}
return f(**kwargs)        # same as saying f(a=5, b=6)
```