# F# SOAP client with reserved word in parameter

Tags: wcf, soap, f#

I'm using the LanguageService (translation service) from Bing. I generated the F# soap client code with svcutil (and modified it a little to got it working) but got stuck with some methods that use the word **to** in their parameters. And it is reserved in F#.

```
 [<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/LanguageService/Translate", ReplyAction="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/LanguageService/TranslateResponse")>]
 abstract Translate :appId:string * text:string * from:string * to:string * contentType:string * category:string -> string
```

I already tried with **_to** and **__to** without luck.

I don't know if there is any way to undefine keywords or define the parameter another way (something like this: [SOAPpy - reserved word in named parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870455/soappy-reserved-word-in-named-parameter-list) ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
abstract Translate :appId:string * text:string * from:string * ``to``:string * contentType:string * category:string -> string
```

Double back-ticks allow you to put almost any string (including spaces and punctuation, and obviously reserved words).